# MySql installation database initialization error

Tags: mysql, database, windows, installation

Im getting an error in the apply configuration part in the mySql installer community edition, it simply gives me and error after i execute with initializing the database, here is the log:

---

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules
Attempting to delete a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306

Deleted 1 rule(s).
Ok.

Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.

Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Updating existing service
Existing service updated
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.11...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
2018-07-06T00:43:22.829759Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-07-06T00:43:22.829791Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-07-06T00:43:22.830226Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-07-06T00:43:22.830354Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
Process for mysqld, with ID 12256, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.11.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database

---

I would appreciate a reply soon, i kind of need it working now.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this issue

> Updating Windows Firewall rules Attempting to delete a Windows Firewall rule with the command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306".

**The thing which worked for me is:** In the step of the installation, when we have to choose the directory, like: `C:\Program Files\MySQL` and `C:\ProgramData\MySQL` for the setup, at this stage we get warnings like this directory has some existing files or it is not free. What I did is I cleared that directory first, then the warning message disappeared from this step and then I continue the installation procedure, and it worked for me. Hope it will work for you as well

Answer (score -1):

This is a Bug in the Installer of 8.0.11. There are changes in the lower_case_table_names variable in the new release. See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html

Nobody can fix this. If you installing the Server the configfile is write before new. Every time. So if you fix this 0.0 to 0 in my.ini the changes will be overwritten.

Somebody have to report a this bug to MySql.

(I am copy pasting from another thread. Having the same issue myself)

Comment: is there some sort of fix?? @user3357353